# Catalog rules not visible on cart/checkout after 2.3 upgrade

Tags: magento2.3, catalog-price-rules

I have catalog rules applied across my website for specific customer groups. I also have tax disabled for those customer groups (B2B customers).

The catalog rules are working fine on the catalog and product views, but when a customer adds a product to their cart, they get the full pricing without catalog rules applied, and they also have tax applied. It is as if the customer is no longer logged in to their customer group, but if I go back to the catalog view, the discount price is clearly visible.

We recently upgraded to 2.3 CE. Everything was working fine on our previous 2.1 installation.

I have emptied index tables and completely reindexed everything. I have "Applied Rules" a number of times. Cleared all cache, cleared FPC, etc.

Any ideas for where I should look to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the newer configuration setting: "Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group" under Customer > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options

From the way this reads, it seems it would only apply to creation of new accounts. However, this setting was perpetually pushing our customer groups back to the default group during checkout. Turning it off ("No") solved the problem.